# How to define a simple function in GLSL for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to dive into the shader language to write some simple fragment shader for my iOS 9+ / Sprite-Kit app. But I am already stuck on trying to call a simple function. Here's my shader code which I bind into my Swift 2.2 app by using the SKShader object from Sprite-Kit:

```
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = getColor();
}

float getColor() {
    return vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

When trying to compile, I get the following errors:

```
2016-06-22 12:53:35.606 ShaderTestGLSL[8425:2478215] Jet: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Compilation failed: 

program_source:8:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'getColor'
    return getColor();
           ^
program_source:12:7: warning: no previous prototype for function 'getColor'
float getColor() {
      ^
program_source:13:16: error: excess elements in scalar initializer
    return vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
               ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Compilation failed: 

program_source:8:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'getColor'
    return getColor();
           ^
program_source:12:7: warning: no previous prototype for function 'getColor'
float getColor() {
      ^
program_source:13:16: error: excess elements in scalar initializer
    return vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
               ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
2016-06-22 12:53:35.608 ShaderTestGLSL[8425:2478215] SKShader failed to compile:
Compilation failed: 

program_source:8:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'getColor'
    return getColor();
           ^
program_source:12:7: warning: no previous prototype for function 'getColor'
float getColor() {
      ^
program_source:13:16: error: excess elements in scalar initializer
    return vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
               ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2016-06-22 12:53:35.629 ShaderTestGLSL[8425:2478215] <SKMetalLayer: 0x154e749d0>: calling -display has no effect.
```

What is wrong with my function definition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues.

First, just as in many other procedural languages, you must declare a function before you use it. In the case of `getColor` being called in `main`, it has not been declared yet. This can be easily resolved by moving the definition of `getColor` above `main` in your file.

Second, `getColor` returns a `float`, however, your `return` statement attempts to return a `vec4`. From the usage in your example, I would assume you would just want to change the return type of the `getColor` function to `vec4`.

Your fixed example would look like this:

```
vec4 getColor() {
    return vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = getColor();
}
```

Comment: Great - thank you very much! Awkward that I missed the return type ;-)